# Cannot run java application on plesk

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I uploaded java web aplication war file on plesk. Another application runs without problems on this host. but for this App, I got this error:

`Actual status of the application does not correspond to the status retrieved from the database.`

I read at this [link](http://kb.odin.com/en/980), the error can be for the following reasons:

- Tomcat service must be running on this server.
- Tomcat service should be enabled on the domain.
- Domain should be properly resolved in DNS to correct IP address.
- Application should be packed into a valid .war package.

Does anyone have a solution to fix this error?

Comment: By default plesk servers dont come with java installed, you can install tomcat which allows you to run java applications. You can do this by Menu on the left, click Tools & Settings.
In the Panel section, click Updates and Upgrades.
Click Add/Remove Components.
Click " + " next to Plesk hosting features.
Select Tomcat Java Servlets support.
Click Continue.
For more info visit https://kb.plesk.com/en/119669

Comment: @pleshy It was great. Thanks